# com.sun.xml.ws.model.Injector <clinit> SEVERE: null

Tags: java, xml, webservice

Intento crear un web service para generar un wsdl para practicar, pero esta saliendo un error no tengo ni idea de donde viene, he puesto las dependencias necesarias, revisado las clases y no tengo ni idea de donde podria venir el error.

Os dejo mi pom.xml:

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>creacion-web-service</groupId>
 <artifactId>web-service-calculadora</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>WebServiceCalculadora</name>


<build>
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.14.0</version>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
         <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
         <version>2.3.1</version>
     </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Y este es el código que intento ejecutar, el proyecto esta creado apartir de Maven, no se si podria ser por la versión de alguna dependencia, he probado en cambiar a unas inferiores y tampoco.

```
public class CalculadoraPublish {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/WS/Calculadora", new CalculadoraImpl());
    }
}
```

Y el mensaje de error es este, he probado en cambiar la versión de glassfish y tampoco, he instalado el tomcat y lo tengo activado, pero esto no va bien:

```
ene 21, 2022 11:08:50 A. M. com.sun.xml.ws.model.Injector <clinit>
SEVERE: null
java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(java.lang.String,[B,int,int,java.lang.ClassLoader,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:573)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.Injector.<clinit>(Injector.java:105)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.WrapperBeanGenerator.createRequestWrapperBean(WrapperBeanGenerator.java:295)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.getRequestWrapperClass(RuntimeModeler.java:375)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processDocWrappedMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:801)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processMethod(RuntimeModeler.java:731)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.processClass(RuntimeModeler.java:491)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.RuntimeModeler.buildRuntimeModel(RuntimeModeler.java:320)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.<init>(DatabindingImpl.java:100)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:74)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingProviderImpl.create(DatabindingProviderImpl.java:58)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingFactoryImpl.createRuntime(DatabindingFactoryImpl.java:120)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createSEIModel(EndpointFactory.java:521)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.create(EndpointFactory.java:300)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.createEndpoint(EndpointFactory.java:164)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:578)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.WSEndpoint.create(WSEndpoint.java:560)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.createEndpoint(EndpointImpl.java:334)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:247)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:141)
    at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:254)
    at com.calculadora.ws.CalculadoraPublish.main(CalculadoraPublish.java:9)
```

Comment: Tienes una pregunta en el SO en inglés con la respuesta correcta:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69637244/java-lang-nosuchmethodexception-sun-misc-unsafe-defineclassjava-lang-string-b
A ver si te sirve :)

Comment: Ya, lo que pasa es que no estoy usando springboot y en la etiqueta build he probado lo que se decia en la pregunta que me has enlazado y tampoco va. Ando ya desesperado :/